# Filtering WooCommerce Orders by Category

Tags: plugins, filters, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I am using WooCommerce as an ordering system online.

I will be having many categories for each products. How can I allow the admin or the shop manager to filter the orders page by product category?

I'm currently using the plugin "WooCommerce Filter Orders by Product" however, I am lost in the SQL queries used in showing these items.

I was able to show the categories using only a SQL query however it doesn't work in the dropdown menu.

```
SELECT wp_terms.term_id,wp_terms.name 
FROM wp_terms 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
```

Comment: Have you researched the topic before posting the question?

Comment: @MaxYudin I have. There is an existing plugin that also does that however, it has a price. I'm trying to edit the code of the plugin itself.

Comment: Your edits will disappear with the first plugin update. Here are [results](https://generatewp.com/filtering-posts-by-taxonomies-in-the-dashboard/) of [20-second research](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+admin+filter+posts+by+category).